# mapping a set of numbers to another set of numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we are given $N$ integer numbers and the $min=1, max=M$ and $N \leq M $ is there any function to map $1...M$ to $1...N$? I mean this function should map every integer number in $[1,M]$ to an any number in $[1,N]$, No matter this mapping function generates real numbers.

---

**UPDATE:**

As you all know Bucket Sort, sorts $N$ numbers with the maximum $M$ in $O(M)$, I need to find this function as a key to limit the numbers in $[1,N]$ then sort them in $O(N)$, so by this key $N$ numbers with the maximum $M$ will be sortable in $O(N)$

Comment: What's wrong with the constant function $1$? Do you have more constraints in mind?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know I could be completely wrong, but it sounds as though OP wants a bijection.  They said $M$ is some positive integer.  Now, we have a set of $N$ numbers, and the min of this set is $1$ and the max is $M$, where $N \leq M$.  It sounds to me (again, I could be **totally wrong**) like they want a bijection from this set to the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, N \}$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The set of functions from $[M]$ to $[N]$ is often denoted $[N]^{[M]}$ whose cardinality is $N^M$; that's how many functions exist, if I understand what you're asking. If you demand continuous functions from $[1, M]$ to $[1,N]$, this can be arranged as well (see: Lagrange Interpolating Polynomials).

Comment: @user46944 There's no bijection between $\{1,\ldots,M\}$ and $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ unless $M=N$. There's also no injection from $\{1,\ldots,M\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ unless $N \geq M$, and no surjection unless $N \leq M$. But it's up to the OP to explain what it is that they want.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  What? If my interpretation was right, we aren't asking for a bijection between $\{1, \dots, M\}$ and $\{1, \dots , N\}$.  The original set is a set of integers.  It has $N$ elements (where $N \leq M$).  The min is $1$ and the max is $M$.  For example, if we take $N = 3$, $M = 7$, then our set could be $\{1, 6, 7\}$.  And we would want a bijection between this and $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

Comment: @user46944 Under this interpretation the answer is *yes*. But I think the OP also wants the function to be defined on all of $\{1,\ldots,M\}$, and allows the output to be any real number in the interval $[1,N]$. Perhaps they have in mind some other assumptions, like the one suggested by pjs36.

Comment: I meant, for example we are given $1,13,6,45$ and I need to map this to numbers in $[1,4]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I understand your question.

> We are given a set $A$ consisting of $N$ integers such that $\min A = 1$ and $\max A = M$. Is there a function $f\colon [1,\ldots,M] \to [1,N]$ that maps $A$ bijectively to $\{1,\ldots,M\}$?

Under this interpretation, you can construct this function as follows. Let $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. The function $f$ maps $a_i$ to $i$, and maps any other number in its domain to $1$.

You can think of many other functions. For example, you can construct a continuous function which has this property. One way is to fix the points $(a_1,1),\ldots,(a_N,N)$, and interpolate linearly between them. You can also construct smoother functions satisfying your requirements, if you so wish.

Comment: Is it possible for this mapping function to generate integer numbers as the mapping result?

Comment: Yes, my first example generates integers.

Comment: If we take this function as a key that maps $N$ numbers from $[1,M]$ to $[1,N]$ then could this function be used in bucket sort to sort $N$ numbers in $O(N)$?

Comment: Drupalist, it seems like you have another question in mind. Perhaps you should ask it instead of adding follow-up questions in the comments.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: In that case, you want one function which is good for all subsets $A$, which is impossible if you insist the mapping always be a bijection.